# PhpStorm plugin

Tags: plugins, phpstorm

I am looking for plugin for PhpStorm that allows me to surround selected text like it is in Sublime Text.

Example:

```
//selected text:
foo();
//press the ' char
//result
'foo();'
```

I totally do not know how such plugin may be named.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a built-in functionality. Just ensure that you have this option enabled:

`Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys --> Surround selection on typing quote or brace`

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much :)